# Quarkus Reactive - Multiple matching properties for name "security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints" Error

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus, mutiny

Using Quarkus I get the following error at execution time:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple matching
> properties for name "security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints"
> property was matched by both public boolean
> io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs
> and public boolean
> io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs. This is
> likely because you have an incompatible combination of extensions that
> both define the same properties (e.g. including both reactive and
> blocking database extensions)

My pom properties are:

```
<compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
<maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
<maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<quarkus-plugin.version>1.13.3.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
<quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
<quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
<quarkus.platform.version>1.13.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
```

And dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-mutiny</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-vertx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-mutiny</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I'm just trying to stream using Multi from mutiny and **Server Sent Elements**:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@RestSseElementType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/stream/{count}/{name}")
public Multi<String> greetingsAsStream(int count, String name) {
    return service.greetings(count, name);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have both classic RESTEasy (`quarkus-resteasy-jsonb`, `quarkus-resteasy-mutiny`) and RESTEasy Reactive (`quarkus-resteasy-reactive`). You need to pick one and stick to it.

For example, if you want RESTEasy Reactive, you'd remove `quarkus-resteasy-mutiny` (no need for extra dependency with RESTEasy Reactive), and replace `quarkus-resteasy-jsonb` with `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb`.

Comment: To expand on this, the error message is much better in Quarkus 2.x and tells you what the actual problem is

Answer (score 0):

```
I am facing a similar problem:
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Multiple
> matching properties for name "security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints"
> property was matched by both public boolean
> io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs
> and
> public boolean io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs. This
> is likely because you have an incompatible combination of extensions that both
> define the same properties (e.g. including both reactive and blocking database
> extensions)

```
I am using Swagger OpenAPIGenerate:

generatorName.set("jaxrs-spec")

Gradle dependencies:
```

dependencies {

> ```
>  implementation(Libs.quarkus_resteasy){
>     exclude(group = "io-quarkus", module = "quarkus-resteasy-runtime")
> }
>  implementationList(LibGroups.quarkus_rest_server)
> }
> ```

```
 Libs.quarkus_resteasy
>  val quarkus_resteasy = "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy"

LibGroups.quarkus_rest_server
>val quarkus_rest_server = listOf(
> >     "io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx",
> >     "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson"      
> >     //"io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive"
>  )

After excluding the clashing module, I am still getting the same error. 
Any poin
```

Comment: Did you remove "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy" ?

Comment: No, it is also there. So I have all these "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy" and "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson" and "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive" and hence the error message on conflicting property.

Comment: did you try to remove "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy" ?